# Melachas on Yom Kippur

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, yom-kippur, yom-tov, muktzeh

Do the additional Rabbinic prohibitions that apply to Yom Tov but not Shabbos (such as the [stricter muktzeh laws](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Which_Melachot_are_forbidden_on_Yom_Tov%3F#Derabbanan_prohibitions_on_Yom_Tov)) also apply to Yom Kippur, in addition to the Shabbos-style prohibitions of that day? That is, does Yom Kippur follow the strictest aspects of both Shabbos and Yom Tov law?

Related: [Noled -- Ossur on Yom Tov, Muter on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/noled-ossur-on-yom-tov-muter-on-shabbos?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Yom Kippur, there is a special rule concerning meal preparation. But apart from this all is identical to Shabbat.
Megila mishna 1, 5:

> אֵין בֵּין שַׁבָּת לְיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים אֶלָּא שֶׁזֶּה זְדוֹנוֹ בִּידֵי אָדָם וְזֶה זְדוֹנוֹ בְּכָרֵת : ‏
>
> There is no difference between sabbath and the day of atonement save only that the deliberate violation of the one is punished by a human court and the deliberate violation of the other by kareth

SA OC [611, 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2973)

> וְכָל שֶׁאָסוּר לְטַלְטְלוֹ בְּשַׁבָּת אָסוּר לְטַלְטְלוֹ בְּיוֹם כִּפּוּר. וְהִתִּירוּ לְקַנֵּב יָרָק וְלִפְצֹעַ אֱגוֹזִים מִן הַמִּנְחָה וּלְמַעְלָה, כְּשֶׁחָל בַּחֹל, וְהָאִדָּנָא נָהֲגוּ לֶאֱסֹר. הגה: אִם נָפְלָה דְּלֵקָה בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים, מֻתָּר לְהַצִּיל סְעֻדָּה אַחַת לְצֹרֶךְ לַיְלָה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁמַּצִּיל בְּשַׁבָּת לִסְעֻדַּת מִנְחָה (רַ''ן פֶּרֶק כָּל כִּתְבֵי). וּכְבָר נִתְבָּאֵר סִימָן של''ד כֵּיצַד נוֹהֲגִים בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה בִּדְלֵקָה בְּשַׁבָּת, וְהוּא הַדִּין בְּיוֹם כִּפּוּר. וְנָהֲגוּ שֶׁהַתִּינוֹקוֹת מְשַׂחֲקִים בֶּאֱגוֹזִים (אֲגֻדָּה וּמַהֲרִי''ל), וְאֵין לִמְחוֹת בְּיָדָם אֲפִלּוּ קֹדֶם מִנְחָה; וְנִשְׁתַּרְבֵּב הַמִּנְהָג מִדִּין הַפְצָעַת אֱגוֹזִים הַנִּזְכָּר (דִּבְרֵי עַצְמוֹ)‏
>
>  Anything that cannot be moved on Shabbos (i.e. muktzah) cannot be moved on the day of atonement. But in the past, when this was not shabbat, from Mincha (Ketana) hour they used to trim vegetables and cracking nuts. But nowaday, we tend to prohibit. ANNOTATION (R.M. Issarles). In case of fire, one meal for the night can be saved... Children used to play with nuts, they must be allowed to this, also before Minha (Aguda, Maharil). Noweday the custom to crack nuts become widespread.

Regarding the difference between Yom Tov and Shabbat see Gemara Betsa 2b:

> With respect to the Sabbath which is stringent so that people will not come to treat it lightly, he taught the Mishnah anonymously according to R`Simeon who is lenient; [with respect to] a Festival which is less stringent so that people might come to treat it lightly, he taught the Mishnah anonymously according to R`Judah who is strict.

Yom kippur is stringent as Shabbat, so his rule regarding this is the rule of Shabbat, not the rule of Yom Tov.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What is the law regarding meal preparation that is special for Yom Kippur? Also, can you definitively confirm that the 2 rabbinical stringencies for Yom Tov (I forget what they are, but I know they are more stringent than Shabbos--I think one involves a prohibition on using something that was newly made during Yom Tov) do not apply to Yom Kippur?

Comment: @SAH i you want I can explain this 2 rabbinical stringencies. etc but there is no reason to beleave that YK is similar to Yom Tov. On tora it is not defined as Yom tov

Comment: @SAH ["בדברים מסוימים בדיני מוקצה החמירו חכמים ביום טוב יותר מאשר בשבת, משום שחששו שמא מתוך שמותר לעשות ביום טוב מלאכות לצורך אוכל נפש, יבואו להקל במלאכות שאסורות בחג, וכשיראו שמחמירים במוקצה יותר, יזהרו לברר בכל דין מה מותר ביום טוב ומה אסור. "](http://ph.yhb.org.il/12-06-06/) the reason of the stringency on YT is the allowed things. In YK nothing similar is allowed

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but I don't read Hebrew; can you summarize? ... My question is, would noled be allowed on Yom Kippur? (Please see the link added to my question.)... And would Yom Kippur take the weaker muktzeh laws (like Shabbos) or the stricter muktzeh laws (like Yom Tov)?

Comment: @SAH Sorry too. the stringencies on Yom Tov are consequences of greet leniencies and are stop sign for leniencies. In Yom Kippur, no leniencies, so no stop

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying that noled is prohibited on Yom Kippur, and the laws of muktzeh on Yom Kippur are stricter than those for Shabbos? Thanks

Comment: @SAH contrariwise

Comment: Perhaps you could add a line or two to your answer summarizing the info that you provided in these comments? If so, I'll accept your answer.  (Comments are often deleted around here, so it's best to put everything in the answer.) Thanks!

Comment: @SAH fixed i hope

Comment: What is "the special rule concerning meal preparation" for Yom Kippur? Thanks!

Comment: @SAH "But in the past, when this was not shabbat, from Mincha (Ketana) hour they used to trim vegetables and cracking nuts"